# In Android Gradle projects, is there a way to pass build variants configuration in nested dependencies?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I got a problem in an Android project.

For example, there are four modules: App, Lib1, Lib2, Lib3.

App:

```
    compile project(":Lib1")
```

Lib1:

```
    compile project(":Lib2")
```

Lib2:

```
    compile project(":Lib3")
```

Now, I configure product flavor for **Both App and Lib3** like this:

```
    productFlavors {
        formal {}
        dev {}
    }
```

When I assemble a build variant for App like :App:assembleFormalRelease, I want Lib3's formalRelease variant to be built.

==============

I know I can achieve this by adding the same productFlavors and configuring like the following in all modules.

```
    configurations {
        devReleaseCompile {}
        devDebugCompile {}
        formalReleaseCompile {}
        formalDebugCompile {}
    }

    dependencies {    
        devReleaseCompile project(path:"xxx", configuration: "devRelease")
        devDebugCompile project(path:"xxx", configuration: "devDebug")
        formalReleaseCompile project(path:"xxx", configuration: "formalRelease")
        formalDebugCompile project(path:"xxx", configuration: "formalDebug")
    }
```

but there are more than FIVE levels of nested dependencies in my working project, I want to know if there is a more simple solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think tasks dependency is what you need.Since assemble tasks are lazy load
In the App module:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
if(task.name.equals('assembleFormalRelease')
     {task.dependsOn ':lib3:assembleFormalRelease'}
}
```

Does it work?any conflicts in your scenario?

Comment: Thanks. But what I need is to add project dependencies , like the `formalReleaseCompile project(path:"xxx", configuration: "formalRelease")` does.